# iPhone App kill my iphone music player?

Tags: iphone, background-process, mpmusicplayercontroller, background-music

As soon as I open app it kills my music player. I dont want user to feel such experience. Sometime user don't want to stop their music player while app browsing. For that purpose I will provide explicitly a button in my app which stop music player.

So what function I need to call and where in my App which doesn't stop music player as soon as I launch app without single second delay or any interruption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with AVAudioSession. **[This Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html)** may help you to achieve that.